# передача несжатого видео по RTP. Чем посмотреть видеопоток?

Tags: online-video, rtp

Занимаюсь передачей несжатого видео по RTP протоколу. Пакеты формирую в соответствии с спецификацией RFC4175. Смотрю в снифере пакеты, которые принимаю - вроде все в соответствует спецификации. Подскажите, с помощью какого плеера можно посмотреть этот видеопоток???

Как я понял VLC плеер не может отобразить сырое видео. Пробовал использовать ffmpeg - ни в какую. Не исключено, что у меня проблема с SDP файлом. Прилагаю его ниже

```
v=0
o=- 2525 1 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=stream
t=0 0
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 127
a=rtpmap:127 RAW/90000
a=fmtp:127 sampling=RGB;width=172;height=144;depth=10;colorimetry=BT709-2;chroma-position=1
```

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: (чисто из интереса) несжатого? а ты не лопнешь? или разрешение низкое?

Comment: разрешение qcif. к тому же при 10 fps. Надеюсь не лопну. Надо увидеть хоть какую то картинку из камеры. Потом, конечно же, это видео будет сжиматься